# Selecting specific COLUMNS after a previous select that returned one ROW

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am completely stumped here and am in need of help.

I have a Table called "2016Blocks" This table has rows for each individual. Each row has columns for every day of the year (365 columns for each row).

I currently have a select statement that will return a single row that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [2016Blocks] WHERE ([OfficialID] = @OfficialID)
```

The above select statement will return one row with 365 columns. Each column will either be blank or have a date in it. The name of the columns are (Blocks1, Blocks2, Blocks3......Blocks365)

I want to now do another select statement on this row to only return columns that have a date in them.

How do I do this?

Comment: no way to do it without some fancy dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use UNPIVOT function for that. As you have 365 columns so you might not want to mention 365 hardcoded column names. For this purpose you can use dynamic query. Finally you can use below query in subquery or insert records in temp table and add filter for BlockValue. Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.column_name)
           from information_schema.columns as C
           where C.table_name = '2016Blocks' and
                 C.column_name like 'Blocks%'
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select id, entityId,
        BlockNumber,
        BlockValue
     from 2016Blocks
     WHERE ([OfficialID] = @OfficialID)
     unpivot
     (
        BlockValue
        for BlockNumber in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via XML.  Null will be eliminated, and no need to specify all 365 fields

```
Declare @2016Blocks table (OfficialID int ,Block1 Date,Block2 Date,Block365 Date)
Insert into @2016Blocks values
(1,'2016-01-01','2016-01-02',null),
(2,'2016-06-15','2016-07-02','2016-08-22')

Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @2016Blocks for XML RAW)

Select ID    = r.value('@OfficialID','int')
      ,Item  = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="OfficialID"]') as B(attr)
```

Returns

```
ID  Item        Value
1   Block1      2016-01-01
1   Block2      2016-01-02
2   Block1      2016-06-15
2   Block2      2016-07-02
2   Block365    2016-08-22
```

> EDIT

**

> I included the ID and Field name to demonstrate the functionality**